# How to retrieve multiple rows from database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve multiple rows from the database and process it for response as service using php code, but I wouldn't retreive all values, only first row from the table is displaying, how can I make dis to work?

Here is my code:

```
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("testing",$conn);
$sql="insert into login (src,dest)values('$from','$tona')";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($res);
setcookie('a',$numrows);
```

Comment: You can just get it by googling...! Show some research effort before asking a question here

Answer (score 2):

**Note** the use of `_mysql` is discouraged for new development ... [please read this on selecting a new API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

This is pretty basic but you need to loop the returned result like so :

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    // your columns are accessible using
    $row['columnname'];
    // or 
    $row[columnnumber];
}
```

[Docs for `mysql_fetch_array` are here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource on success or false on failure

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("testing",$conn);
$sql="insert into login (src,dest)values('$from','$tona')";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($res);
while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

    echo $result['src']."<br/>";

}
setcookie('a',$numrows);
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_* is deprecated
use

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($res);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you using mysql instead of mysqli. Try changing to mysqli instead, because this will become the new standard. As of version PHP 5.5.0 mysql will become deprecated.

Comment: Oh, sorry I see that @ManseUK has already mentioned it to you.